# How to get list of all daydreams installed on android phone

Tags: android, list, screensaver, daydream

I have managed to get list of all live wallpapers installed on phone. But i would like to get the list of all daydreams installed on my android phone. Can someone please help me with the intent that i should use to get this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code prints all the Daydream available in the device:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
Intent dreamIntent = new Intent(DreamService.SERVICE_INTERFACE);
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = packageManager.queryIntentServices(dreamIntent, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfoList) {
    if (resolveInfo.serviceInfo == null) {
        continue;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(resolveInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)));
}
```